# Can a powder be transparent?

Tags: solid-state-physics, laser, refraction

I know that even glass powder is white due to refraction and internal reflection.  So to be transparent, the index of refraction would need to be close to 1 (air).

I also know that the index of refraction of a material can approach 1 near an absorption band (say "transparency" only needs to apply to a monochromatic laser).   There seems to be experiments that prove this, but can a material really be transparent at an absorption band?  Or does the index of refraction just approach 1, but in actuality the light is absorbed (and the laser would just vaporize the powder instead of propagating through it?)

Comment: Hi Daniel. If I understand your question correctly the title is misleading since it's really asking if the refractive index of a transparent material can be unity.

Comment: True I guess.  Title is the intended application, the description is just my hack attempt at solving it.  I wanted to leave it open to any other solution that I wouldn't know how to ask for (like some QM principle that would apply to tiny particles).  Is that ok here?

Comment: At an absorption band the real part of the material might be unity but the imaginary part is non-zero. Even if you neglect absorption inside the material this also leads to strong reflection at the surface. A typical practical solution is to fill the gaps in the powder with a liquid with very similar refractive index.

Comment: Would it be possible to find a frequency where a working gas has a higher refraction index due to being closer to resonance?  I guess that would cause it to reflect off/absorb in the gas.